# Rails 3.1 Assets: What's the advantage of per-controller stylesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

Just messing around with Rails 3.1, which separates stylesheets via controllers.

I'm assuming there are benefits to this, but I'm struggling to determine what they are. Seems I have to include scss variables/mixins in every stylesheet, and finding elements I want to edit takes a little more time, and few of my styles lend themselves to a particular controller anyhow.

So, what am I missing? What's the "cool stuff" re: per-controller stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it exists in the scaffolding doesn't mean it's necessarily useful--IMO at best it's very niche, perhaps if you have some very-targeted CSS for a controllers.

I think general usage of per-controller stylesheets would be rare, but I'm curious to hear other opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I find the discussion very interesting, it reminds me to old days where people suspected that object-orientation has any value. For me there are a lot of similarities:

On the left terms from object-orientation, on the right from the HTML world:

- class - CSS file per controller
- method - selector e.g. with `#id`
- superclass - import to e.g. compass framework files (`@import "compass/utilities/tables/scaffolding";`)

We are trained when doing web applications to use all files for all views, and use different `id`s for different views to denote that they should be rendered differently. By using a stylesheet per controller, and adding to assets the option to include that stylesheet (only) for the right controller, you could use the same `#id`s with different rules, so you are able to share layouts that will be rendered then differently.

A simple example could be that the per controller stylesheet denotes the background color, so by calling actions from different controllers, the background color shows the context in which your are working. (I do not say that this would be a clever idea or nice to the user, but it is technically possible.)

So I do think that this additional technique has a value in itself, but we have to learn for what it is good for.

Answer (score 1):

From the explanation I've heard, it makes it easier to organize resources

essentially they all get combined and loaded all together in the the end, so really, it's just for organization.

Comment: Well that's pity. I still have to write that freakin' `<body id="<%= controller.controller_name %>">` in layouts and divide css with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on what you are optimizing for. The default approach allows you to partition of styles and put them in files that match the current scope (the controller). This is in line with The Rails Way of doing things.

In production these files don't matter because they all get bundled up together. In the good old days you would have had multiple requests and therefore a performance hit.

The problem comes when you want to maximise use of the cascade, and optimise rules over a whole site, such as the OOCSS approach.

I prefer to structure my CSS around a common reset file, layout file and work from there, building up and refactoring as I go.

Having things spread over many files moves things out from being under your nose all the time, and may (IMHO) result in a less discipled approach to structuring your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

While stylesheets-per-controller has potential value based on the app you're building, it's of course not right for every app. Keep in mind that the behavior of "all stylesheets are compiled together" is just a default--you can change the main stylesheet manifest file to include what you want, or have many different manifests to have different compiled files in production. Check out [the Railscast on the asset pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) if you're looking for more info.